# How to use JavaScript WYSIWYG editor Lexical using Vanila JS?

Tags: javascript, lexicaljs

I want to use Lexical Editor for my website. So far I have used TinyMCE and it was easy to use: I downloaded TinyMCE, saved it on the server and inserted the necessary JS into my web pages.

But I don't understand the instructions on https://lexical.dev/docs/getting-started/quick-start how to use Lexical, where can I download it (to put it to the server) or how should I use it on my site?

Comment: Despite the claims, that documentation is not for vanilla JS, it is for JS using npm or a compatible package manager and a bundler such as Vite.

Comment: You'll need a bundler to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So the procedure is:
1. install npm
2. install Lexical using npm:
npm install --save lexical
3. somehow make it work locally (using npm JS libraries in web pages is somewhat mysterious to me, any recommended tutorial?)
4. Use bundler to make one JS file and use it on the server.
Is it right?